# Nexus nx-usertoken-current privilege and User token Missing in 3.20.1-01

Tags: sonatype, nexus3

I am using nexus repository Manager 3.20.1-01 version and i need to enable User token option to generate token.How can i enable this feature.

NOTE:
I have identified that nx-usertoken-current privilege is missing in my application.

Answer (score 2):

The user token feature requires that a license be installed into Nexus Repo.  Have you installed a license? If so, try restarting it, after initial license installation you need to restart to enable the pro features.

Comment: Very disappointing of Nexus to move simple login security to the paid version. {sigh}